How to connect an outlet across the room to the light switch by the door
How do i connect an outlet across the room to the light switch by the door. The light switch by the door only controls a ceiling fan and light fixture in the fan. I want the light switch to control an outlet across the room, next to the bed, for a light. Is this a difficult as it sounds?

Yes it is difficult. The degree of difficulty can run from annoyingly to absolutely confounding.  This depends on whether cable can be run through an overhead space (Attic) and down the wall or if drywall needs to be ripped out to run cable.  Maybe look into a smart outlet or one that can be operated by remote.

It can be done, usually by going up to the ceiling or under the floor.  Better question is what will that outlet control/power?  Can add a switch above the outlet to control it.

Yes, it is as difficult as it sounds.
Normally, the wiring from the switch, as you have described it, goes UP to the light in the ceiling. It usually comes from the light down to the switch and then back up to the light so there is no wiring down to the basement or crawl space from the switch to connect to.
Consequently, to get the switch to control the receptacle across the room you would need to fish wire up to the existing switch from the basement and then run it to the receptacle in question.
I would probably chop a two gang box in to the existing switch and expand that to a two gang box to allow a second switch that goes down and across to the receptacle in question.
This will be an undertaking for a DYIer that has never done it before but is quite doable if you have the ambition for it.
Anyway you look at it, there is some rewiring to be done to achieve what you want and it will take some doing.

Yes it is difficult. The degree of difficulty can run from annoyingly to absolutely confounding. This depends on whether cable can be run through an overhead space (Attic) and down the wall or under the room or if drywall needs to be ripped out to run cable.
Maybe look into a smart outlet or remote control outlet and switch.

I mean, you could run raceway or something, but that aesthetic isn't for everybody.  I like the smart outlet/switch idea.
